# USB drive mount to access and send information to

Tags: command-line, usb-flash-drive

```
%~d0:\Tools\Fionas_Collection.bat %1 %2
set Toolpath = %1:\Tools\
set Collectdrive = %2:\Collect\
set /p Case= "What is your case number?"
echo Case Number: %Case% >> %CollectDrive%:\Collect\"%Case%_CaseFile.txt"
set /p Name= "What is your name?"
echo Examiners Name: %Name% >> %CollectDrive%:\Collect\"%Case%_CaseFile.txt"
```

Trying to open my USB drive and run this program that has a bunch of commands to run but every time I run it in CMD it says the filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. I am not understanding why I keep getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the spaces around the `=` signs.

```
set Toolpath=%1:\Tools\
set Collectdrive=%2:\Collect\
```